# Define a relation $ \sim$ on $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus (0,0)$ by $(a,b)\sim (c,d)$ if there is some real number x with $a=xc$ and $b=xd$.

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations

Define a relation $ \sim$  on  $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus (0,0)$ by $(a,b)\sim (c,d)$ if there is some real number $x$ with $a=xc$ and $b=xd$. 
I need to prove the relation is an equivalence relation and determine the equivalence classes.

Here's what I have started.

Reflexive: Let $(a,b) \epsilon  \sim$, then $a=1\cdot a$ and $b=1\cdot b$. Thus $(a,b)\sim(a,b)$ and $\sim$ is reflexive.

Can I have a nudge to finish the rest?

Even more important though...can I some deeper intuition to their relation? Help with understanding that will help me determine the equivalence classes on my own.

Comment: Viewing $(a,b)$ as a vector from $(0,0)$ to $(a,b)$  then the relation says $V\sim U\iff V = xU$  is a scaling of $U$ by some real $x$ (necessarily $x\neq 0$ since $V\neq (0,0)$ by hypothesis). That this is an equivalence relation is equivalent to the fact that the scalars $\Bbb R\backslash0$ contain $1$ (reflexive) and are closed under inverses (symmetric)  and multiplication (transitive) i.e. the scalars $\Bbb R\backslash0$ form a *group*.

Answer (score 1):

Symmetry comes from the fact that you can divide by $x$ since neither $a$ or $b$ are $0$, and transitivity comes from considering the product of $x_1$ and $x_2$.

For what the equivalence classes are, think of $\mathbb{R}^2$ as the Euclidean plane, and imagine lines through the origin.

Comment: If $x = 0$ then we have $a = b = 0$, but we've forbidden that from the choice of set we're working on.

Comment: Then for symmetry I can say: If $(a,b),(c,d))\epsilon\sim$, then $ a=xc, b=xd$ and so $c=x^{-1}a, d=x^{-1}b$. Thus $\sim$ is symmetric.

Comment: Exactly. You will probably also want to include a line about why $x^{-1}$ exists.

Comment: Transitivity: If $(a,b), (c,d), (e,f) \epsilon  \sim$, then 
$a=xc, b=xd$
$c=xe, d=xf$ 
Thus, $a=x^{2}e, b=x^{2}f$. 
Therefore, $\sim$ is transitive.

Comment: Yes, thanks. Since $x \epsilon \mathbb{R}, x^{-1} \epsilon  \mathbb{R}$

Comment: @Denise Not quite, on both counts. Why would the $x$ for the first pair equal the $x$ for the second pair? And what if $x = 0$? Then $x^{-1} \notin \mathbb{R}$. Argue as to why $x \neq 0$ (see my first comment for why).

Comment: Got it! So in ~ two points are related if they are lying on the same straight line passing through the origin? Then the equivalence classes are composed of vectors (nonzero) which are scalar multiples of each other?

Comment: That's exactly right.